# form fields not passing through when submit is done via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated. I have an html form with two fields. When I run the page and submit the form with a submit button, the field values pass through ok. But if I run the same page and submit with javascript as I show here, the receiving file shows null values for both x and y.

Source File:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
          document.invoice.x.value = "1";
          document.invoice.y.value = "2";
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" name="invoice" id="invoice" action="process_payment.php">
X: <input type="text" name="x"> Y: <input type="text" name="y">
<script>document.forms["invoice"].submit();</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Target File (process_payment.php):

```
<?php
    session_start();

print "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); print("</pre>");
?>
```

Output I am getting:

```
Array
(
    [x] => 
    [y] => 
)
```

Comment: That is most certainly *not* how to set input field's values in JavaScript.

Comment: Its possible that your `<script>document.forms["invoice"].submit();</script>` is executing before your `<head><script> document.invoice.x.value = "1"; document.invoice.y.value = "2"; </script></head>` executes. Try combining the scripts, with the `.submit()` right after setting the values.

Comment: Thanks Sean. That's exactly what happened. As soon as I implemented your suggestion, it worked!! Alexis, this is not normally how it is done but we have to under the circumstances of our application.

Comment: @firpo , you can Accept Answer if it solves your problem OK ? So that future visitors will also get proper answer.

Comment: use `document.getElementsByName` like `document.getElementsByName("x").value="1"`

Answer (score 0):

[Please check this](http://jsfiddle.net/4262nrm9/)

Use below BEFORE body Close tag [check This](http://jsfiddle.net/4262nrm9/2/)

```
<script>
      document.invoice.x.value = "1";
      document.invoice.y.value = "2";
</script>
```

OR use jQuery

```
<script>
          $("[name='x']").val("1");
          $("[name='y']").val("2");

</script>
```

Comment: he has not tagged jquery.

Comment: I don't know jQuery yet, but hope to get into it soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can set your value in javascript like this:

```
document.getElementsByName("x").value="1";
document.getElementsByName("y").value="2";
```

and to submit the form use:

```
document.forms["invoice"].submit();
```